# What changes is necessary in Module.php and other files for add table in db

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm a beginner in zendframework2. I do example Album in zendframework website, and now I want to add a table in db and do same operations, but I don't know what changes are necessary in `Module.php`, `AlbumController.php` (and other files) and methods.

Please explain necessary changes completely.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and exactly what is the specific problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the [Album tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html) and check out the page about [database and models](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html).

Simplified, the steps are:

1. Create your new model
2. Create a table class
3. Create two services in the service manager, one for the table class and one for the table gateway
4. Fetch the album table in the controller

Step #3 is a modification in the `Module.php` class and explained in [this section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable). Step #4 is a change in the controller and explained [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#back-to-the-controller).